# Reform Wedding No Ketubah

Tags: halacha, marriage, reform-judaism

What is the status of children born to parents that had a Reform wedding without a ketubah prior to their birth?
Are these children considered the product of unmarried parents?

Comment: Are the parents considered Jewish by Rabbinic standards?

Comment: They are both Jewish by rabbinic standards.

Comment: There is no such legal category in Judaism as the product of unmarried parents.

Comment: See here http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/48775/13811

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are non-Orthodox marriages recognized by Orthodox rabbis?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/48405/are-non-orthodox-marriages-recognized-by-orthodox-rabbis)

Comment: @mevaqesh I recommend that you post an answer

Comment: what about having two kosher witnesses?

Comment: Is not nida the bigger problem?